# PHP: why the URL is missing one section?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I'm trying to use TimThumb to display image on my blog

```
<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>&w=290&h=160
```

the above is the code I use

The problem is that the image doesn't display because the URL come out something like this.

```
http://myurl.com/wp-content/themes/ThemeName/timthumb.php?src=&w=290&h=160
```

In which is suppose to be like this for example

```
http://myurl.com/wp-content/themes/ThemeName/timthumb.php?src=http://myurl.com/wp-content/uploads/i0n1c.png&w=290&h=160
```

As you can see above is missing the part from `src=` and that missing part is this code `<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>` I've tested this code separately and it works just fine but when I combine them together then it doesn't display it properly?

Is there something I have to add to make it works?

UPDATE:

Here is the function I use to grab the image

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

and here is the code to call the URL path for the image.

```
<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
```

Comment: have you tried var_dump($image) ?

Comment: @Hajo can you give me some more hint or information? I'm not really expert in php as I'm going to take PHP course in this summer.

Comment: <?php print_r($image); ?> insert that somewhere near the problem for testing and look up if the [0] key contains the data your url is missing or if its another one or even not in there. make sure to cut it afterwards from source ;)

Comment: `var_dump($image)` and tell us what you got ...

Comment: nothing display in the page when I insert this code <?php print_r($image); ?>

Comment: @Ali checked the html source code, too?

Comment: @Hajo yes I did check and nothing display.

Comment: does your timthumb code work on another location?

Comment: @Hajo I didn't try it with another location yet but when I manually insert the missing part to that timthumb and it does work.

Comment: well how can wordpress know about that thimbtumb image location? it must be transfered somehow to your $image array. seen such problems in many wordpress themes that forgot to extend the data moved to the template file.

Comment: I actually have a function that catch the first image uploaded I will update it to my question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tested this code separately and it works just fine

That code should output the variable, so you did it in another context, where the value is properly set.

Update:

have you checked the *generated source code*? You have exta backticks here:

```
?src='<?php echo $image[0]; ?>'&w=
     _                        _
```

Comment: The thing is when I only use this <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"  /> I will see the image display with the right URL just fine but that is the version without timthumb but when I tried the code above then it just missing the URL for the image part.

Comment: I was just to show that I was using that code. I've updated my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: now it works after I change the variable name to something different. Thanks!